# Java JOptionPane from a created thread - window not showing components

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, synchronization, joptionpane

I'm working on a application that reads strings from a document and replaces every occurance of a given word with another word (by user input).

The program runs with three seperate threads ,one for reading data from file to the buffer, one for modifying the strings and one for writing the output.

However, if a checkbox is marked as notify-user then I need to ask the user if he wants to replace the substring at a given 'hit'. Now here is the problem, when I try to use JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...) from the modify-thread then the window doesn't contain any content (blank white box).

I also tried to use SwingUtilities.InvokeLater(new Runnable(){ ...logic...} which did work for showing the confirm-box but the other threads continued running in pararell (I need them to stop and wait for user input).

```
 /**
 * Checks the status of the string at each position in the buffer. If the status = Status.New and the String-object
 * matches to the string to replace then it will be replaced with the String-object replaceString.
 * <p>
 * If the Status of the object is anything other than Status.New then the thread will be blocked.
 * <p>
 * When done, the status of the modified object is changed to Status.Checked.
 */
public synchronized void modify() {
    try {
        while (status[findPos] != Status.New) {
            wait();
        }

        String oldString = buffer[findPos];
        if (buffer[findPos].equals(findString)) {
            buffer[findPos] = replace(findString, replaceString, start, findString.length());
        }

        start += oldString.length() + 1;
        status[findPos] = Status.Checked;

        findPos = (findPos + 1) % maxSize;

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    notify();

}

/**
 * Replaces the strSource with strReplace and marks the word in the source-tab JTextPane. The start argument
 * represents the index at position to replace the substring, the size argument represents the substring's
 * length.
 *
 * TODO : if notifyUser -> ask for user prompt before replacing.
 *
 * @param strSource  : String
 * @param strReplace : String
 * @param start      : int
 * @param size       : int
 * @return s : String
 */
public String replace(String strSource, String strReplace, int start, int size) {
    String s = strSource;
    DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter highlightPainter =
            new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.YELLOW);


    //Ask user if he wants to replace the substring at position 'start'.
    if (notifyUser) {
        int x= JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "TEST", "TEST", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    } else {
        try {

            textPaneSource.getHighlighter().addHighlight(start, start + size,
                    highlightPainter);


        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        s = strReplace;
        nbrReplacement++;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Your question seems pretty broad; as in essence: if you want code that runs in different threads to "sync" its behavior; well, then you have to write the code for that. In other words: your whole design/implementation needs to be build around that idea ... and that is asked a lot to explain; as it would easily take hours of discussions to get this right. My suggestion: forget about the UI parts for now. Look into tutorials and figure how to "sync" several threads on some work. And then, when you mastered that; you look into adding the UI stuff.

Comment: Thanks, but the synchronization is not the issue, I have made the program to run concurrently and correct. I just want to be able to get user input from one of the threads that calls on the synchronized .modify() which in turn calls on .replace(...) where I want the JOP to show in the first if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a ThreadLocal variable which is shared between threads. then you must check it in every thread you want to suspend it.